# From whom do the people from The Scene get money?

Tags: distribution, piracy

I have read the [interview](https://torrentfreak.com/former-movie-piracy-scene-member-speaks-out-101029/) from former member of [The Scene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warez_scene) and the thing that got me interested is from whom does the group get the money?

> Scene member: "Yes. Absolutely. Money and those accusations have gone on for years. I can attest with certainty that I know groups that have sold."

To whom did they sell?

Who buys pirated copyrighted material like television shows and series, movies, music, music videos, games, applications, ebooks, and pornography from Scene groups?

Comment: I don't know who voted for closing because it's "unclear what I'm asking" but I think that the question is pretty clear. I can edit for more detail but please leave a comment then!

Comment: I have edited so that is more clear what I'm asking.

Comment: I think its a valid question and its about unauthorized movie distribution which we should allow/

Comment: Pirated movies are all over every street corner in major cities.  Pirated software is big on ebay, there are even people who produce fully-legit looking MS discs complete with holograms.  Craigslist is also a big pirate resource.

Comment: Questions about movie production and distribution are on topic here.  This is kind of a grey area - being illegal distribution, but I don't see why that specifically makes it off-topic.

Comment: I think, in general, you are asking "who makes money from movie piracy?" That we're referring to 'the scene' specifically seems somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: No, I'm asking specifically from whom do GROUPS get money, not generally about movie piracy. @DA

Comment: @Davidenko perhaps part of the confusion is that the RIAA likes to call file sharing 'piracy' while historically, 'piracy' referred to the *selling* of copies--not the sharing?

Answer (score 2):

I want to go point by point.

**To whom did they sell? Who buys pirated copyrighted material?**

**Pirated movie distribute**, they sell it through pirated DVD and CD's which are quite cheaper and in trend in under-developed countries. They are very much common in Asian market.

**From whom do the people from The Scene get money?**

**Advertisement**. Torrent website link have too many advertisement and even few famous torrent force you to download codec (YiFi), in the case of Yifi print sometimes you need to complete few step before getting codec, which are to download few software, plug-in or add-on etc. Even through YiFi torrent mostly work after the codec but few other also are fake and give Trojan like viruses.

And few don't even want to make money, they just want to make their name.

Comment: Ok, I get the advertisement part, but people that distribute DVD's and CD's can download pirated materials for free from torrent sites and then distribute it. Or they maybe contribute by paying to groups?

Comment: Teh Scene have got nothing to do with torrents.

Answer (score 2):

Most "Scene" groups do it for one reason; they have a Robin Hood complex.  They don't ask for any money, they don't want any money, they want recognition.  Those who reverse-engineer games/software do it mainly for the challenge.

There are a small set of groups in the scene who do it for money.  As for who buys what they sell; on many street corners in NYC you can find pirated games, software, CDs and DVDs.  They're more common than you think.  There are also people who huck on ebay and craigslist. There are the people who will brashly walk into bars and sell to patrons (I've seen that in my hometown of Stamford, CT the last time I visited).  Any of these people can be part of the scene, or hired by people connected.  This segment is very small, though.

When I was in F0SI, a few people sold limited amounts of copies, just enough to keep our server running and a small "kittie" for buying new releases.  This way, we didn't go broke trying to get the goods out.

Comment: F0SI..........?